# Retrofit 2 how to resolve this json that the key is variable? (android)

Tags: retrofit2

Retrofit 2 how to  resolve this json that the key is  variable? (android),Thank you for help.

Comment: what json ?? please post the related JSON and code you have tried.

Comment: {
    "20161108": [
        {
            "name": "0",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "1",
            "value": 0
        }
    ],
    "20161223": [
        {
            "name": "0",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "1",
            "value": 0
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I want to resolve this json, but the key "20161108" and "20161223" is variable, so i don't know how to resolve ,  thank you for your help !